# Installing Mesos from Mesosphere yum repository

Tags: python, mesos, mesosphere

I am trying to install Mesos to in my container (CentOS 7) to have the Mesos libraries installed for my scheduler (python).

I followed 'Installing Mesos packages' section in https://open.mesosphere.com/downloads/mesos/

After successfully running:

```
$ rpm -Uvh http://repos.mesosphere.com/el/7/noarch/RPMS/mesosphere-el-repo-7-3.noarch.rpm
$ yum -y install --enablerepo=mesosphere mesos
$ pip install protobuf
```

I see Mesos packages in pip

However, from python, I cannot import Mesos scheduler driver:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mesos.interface import Scheduler
>>> from mesos.native import MesosSchedulerDriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mesos/native/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from mesos.scheduler import MesosSchedulerDriver
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mesos/scheduler/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ._scheduler import MesosSchedulerDriverImpl as MesosSchedulerDriver
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mesos/scheduler/_scheduler.so: undefined symbol: svn_txdelta2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not an expert on this, but I think the packages don't install the development dependencies. Have a look at http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/

In your case, you seem to miss a SVN library.

Comment: The getting-started page instructs to build mesos from source. Is that a prerequisite to running a custom mesos framework?

Regarding the missing SVN library, what do I need to install the missing library? I tried the following with no luck: 
$ yum install subversion mod_dav_svn

Comment: Try `$ yum install subversion-devel`

Comment: Thanks @Tobi, that worked after I added the WANdisco SVN Repo 1.8